In api platform, is it possible to add automatically all controllers routes in documentation?
I use symfony for create en API.
And I would like to know if it's possible to add automatically all controllers routes in documentation ?
I don't want to declare every route I created in the entity. I would like to declare the route with its configuration in the controller, but I want to appear in the documentation also as in nelmio bundle.
Is it possible ?
I don t want to declare routes in the entity as there :
#[ApiResource(operations: [
    new Get(
        controller: ProductController::class,
        name: 'get_product',
        requirements: ['id' => '\d+'],
    ),
    new Post(
        controller: ProductController::class,
        name: 'post_product',
    )
])]
class Product
{

But I want to declare my routes in the controller only :

class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(
        path: '/product/{id}',
        name: 'get_product',
        requirements: ['id' => '\d+']
    )]
    public function index($id): Response
    {
        return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'ProductController',
        ]);
    }
}

And I want to see it in the api documentation routes.
